# getting all label text and input values from div in array with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="control-group"
<label for="Student_DateOfEnrolment" class="control-label">Date</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" value="1.1.0001 0:00:00" name="Student.DateOfEnrolment" id="Student_DateOfEnrolment" data-val-required="The Datum vpisa field is required." data-val-date="The field Datum vpisa must be a date." data-val="true" class="input-xlarge focused">
</div>
</div>
```

I have many form input fields like in example. Can I somehow read all label text and input vales to array and show it later on. I would like to collect all at one from some div.

What i did until now:

```
$(function(){ 

                                $('#MyWizard').each(function (i, div) {
                                    alert('in here');
                                    $(div).find('input').each(function (j, element) {
                                        alert('lll');
                                    });
                                });
                            });
```

I get alert "in here" but no "lll"

Comment: Yes, of course you can.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that each one of your inputs is set up in a `control-group` with the input being in a `controls` container?

Comment: yes it is safe to asume.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each `<div>` with class `control-group`, from which we can drill down into the `<label>` and `<input>` elements, collect their "values", put turn the whole thing into an array:

```
$(function() {
    var labelValuePairs = $('#MyWizard .control-group').map(function(el) {
        return {
            label: $('.control-label', el).text(),
            value: $('.controls :input', el).val()
        };
    }).get();
    console.log(labelValuePairs);
});
```

The output to the console would be something like:

```
> [Object]
  > 0: Object
     label: "Date"
     value: "1.1.0001 0:00:00"
```

This is an array of objects, the 0<sup>th</sup> item being an object with the properties displayed.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WLhm6/)</kbd>